# JS: Вопрос на понимание наследования в js

Tags: javascript

Есть конструктор:

```
var Human = function(name){
    this.name = name;
};
```

Запишу новый метод в прототип конструктора:

```
Human.prototype.say = function(what){ console.log(this.name + " : " + what) };
```

Теперь каждый объект, созданный с помощью ключевого слова new, будет наследовать Human.prototype, как например, этот:

```
var alex = new Human("Alex");
```

Только так следует добавлять новые методы в конструктор?

Comment: что значит _добавлять новые методы в конструктор_?

Comment: и причём тут наследоавние ?

Comment: Есть еще функциональный стиль [ссылка](http://learn.javascript.ru/oop)

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/class-inheritance